# Dynamically Identifying frequency of errors in logs

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I will start out by staying, I am not a developer. My coding skills are elementary so I apologise if this has been answered in another place and I missed it.

Our software, which runs on customers machines directly, generates and uploads "error" logs.  Presently, these logs just get uploaded to a folder on our server, and once every 30 minutes or so, a service reads them for the customers ID and moves them to the customer's account. There they sit until someone manually looks at them and decides if they mean something and what to do, if anything.

This works well for retroactively looking to see if the customer has the same issue as another customer.

What I would like to do is have the service that reads the log for the customers ID also use some sort of pattern analysis to identify each unique error and then record the frequency over time. Such as 1 day, 3 days, 5 days, 1 week, 2 weeks a month, etc.

Part of the issue is that the error logs dynamically generated on the customers' machines. Some of the errors are prewritten by us in code, but many of the errors we get come from 3rd party sources and integration. So many of the errors we get are not something we would know to look for ahead of time.

A good example of this, Dell changed one of their system tools that started deleting several of our files; it generated a specific error. Not one we wrote, but still specific enough that once we identified it, we could track it.

So, after that long winded explanation. Is there a good way to do this type of analysis? We typically prefer using the .net frame work as much as possible. Most of the results I see depends on looking for an existing pattern, which isn't quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to think about ways off the happy path, but one perspective is to distinguish between:

- Predictable problems; let's call those *failures*.
- Unpredictable problems; let's call those *exceptions*.

Predictable failures should be dealt with in code. This is possible, exactly *because* they are predictable. Since the code can deal with these failures, there's little reason to log them.

The truly exceptional problems are the ones you can't predict. Those you log. Since you can't predict them, however, I don't see how you can effectively analyse them without human interpretation.

If a third-party system tends to cause problems, set up [Contract Tests](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContractTest.html) and monitor those.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look in to that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a rookie in this coding stuff. I just came across a code that deals with frequency of words in texts. I'm not sure if that's the problem but it's still an idea right? :)

```
def count_errors(logs):
    result = {}
    for errors in logs:
        if errors not in result:
            result[errors] = 0
        result[errors] += 1
    return result
```

it gives a dictionary of errors as keys and number of their appearances as values.

I'm also curious about the solution though :)